# Canonical / invertible transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, definition, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

What distinguishes a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) from an ordinary invertible Coordinate transformation?

I understand what canonical is but searching the difference between canonical and invertible didn't get me any answers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easiest to answer with one momentum and one position.  In this case, a necessary and sufficient condition for the transformation to be canonical is that the determinant of the transformation be $+1$.

There are plenty of transformations for which Det$\ne 1$; all those are therefore not canonical.  Thus for instance the transformation
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ p \end{array}\right) \to \left(\begin{array}{c}x' \\ p' \end{array}\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ p \end{array}\right)
\end{align}
is not canonical, even if it is invertible.